# Is it possible to rebroadcast/relay a live FFMPEG stream?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, streaming, broadcast

In short: I am currently reading in a live FFMPEG stream in a Java application, and need to essentially 're-broadcast' the stream to another address as it comes in, frame-by-frame. Currently using bytedeco's wrapper: [bytedeco/ffmpeg](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/)

The FFMPEG data coming in has 2 'streams': One with video frames and one with KLV data.

The application is currently decoding these packets/data streams and displaying/performing various operations on them so I have access to the incoming data in several forms throughout the pipeline.

The ideal solution would be to take the raw AVPacket just as it's been read in from the input context (see *av_read_frame()*), and push it straight back out to a specified address/addresses.

Having looked over the docs I'm unsure if this is even possible, and certainly can't find any examples of this kind of relay being used.

If it makes a difference, there will be 1 or 2 specific addresses to restream the data to. A traditional broadcast will not be possible/ideal.

Comment: TUrwin could you please inform whether you managed to relay this stream properly? I have the same issue to resolve.